# Codeigniter application showing 404 on first load and after refresh it shows the actual page

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, http-status-code-404

I am developing an application in `Codeigniter`. I have uploaded the project to the server and want to access it using URL `www.example.com/xyz/`.

`xyz` is the folder where the project is located. It was previously working, but now it is showing "**404 page not found**". Every time when I load the page using URL I get `404 Error` and when I refresh the same page with 404, it gets executed and shows the actual page. I have it on my route.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Member';
```

I have Member controller with index function.

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Maybe an issue with a trailing slash on the url?

Comment: No, This is not the case. I have already checked.

Comment: What is `$config['base_url']` value?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set `base_url()` in `application/config/config.php` file correctly and `(.htaccess)` files is there